# How many external monitors are supported my laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I don't know if this is the right place for this question but I think it works,

I have a Dell G3 15 Laptop and want to setup some external monitors for it. It has a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphic card. After some research I discovered you probably could, but seeing as the laptop only has one hdmi connection, and no other video connections, I don't know. Right now, I have my laptop monitor and one externial display running. The only connections it has are,

2.0 HDMI port (1)

Network port (1)

USB 3.1 Gen 1 port (2)

SD-card slot (1)

USB 2.0 port (1)

and Security-cable slot (for Noble locks)

Comment: Connecting a USB dock may extend the number of screens, however, the specs of the graphics card will list rhe maximum resolution it can push, and this will define the number of screens the system can theoretically support.

Answer (score 0):

The USB 3.1 Gen 1 ports should be able to push the output trough a USB-C Docking. You can see examples of such products by simply googling USB-C Dockings or USB 3.1 Gen 1. the number of screens the system supports is dependent on the grapichs card as music2myear said.

You can use external, USB-connected, graphics adapters to exceed this limit. Since these cards would only depend on an usb-connection it would not be limited by your graphics card. (try searching for USB Video cards or similar)

Hope this helps.